# meta_query with multiple key

Tags: meta-query

I have a search input then I want to display all the data searched in multiple **meta_key**. How can I make it?

This is my **code**

```
$filter = array(
    'post_type'     => 'request',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        "relation" => "AND",
        array(
            'key' => array($key1, $key2, $key3),
            'value' => $search_value,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: try with `"compare" => "IN"`. look here for other possibilities : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters

Answer (score 2):

`key` in a meta query needs to be a string, you can't pass multiple keys to a single meta query. You'll need add a query for each key:

```
$filter = array(
    'post_type'      => 'request',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => $key1,
            'value'   => $search_value,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => $key2,
            'value'   => $search_value,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => $key3,
            'value'   => $search_value,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Note that I set `'relation'` to `'OR'` so that results will be returned for posts that match any of the keys, rather than all. If you need results to have matches for all the keys, change it back to `'AND'`.